# error.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, web-services

I am very new to JAVA webservices. I am creating a soap based webservice in java using apache axis2-1.5.6. I have deployed the service on local machine . Now I want to fetch the data from database. Is there any way to perform the same as I have created the JDBC connection but while creating the connection to the database I am getting the following exception...

error.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.

I have placed the sqljdbc.jar file in my WEB-INF but still getting the same error. Please provide me any suggestion what is going wrong with my web service.

Comment: If you're using an Apache connection pool you need to put it into the container's lib directory, not your own.

Comment: Have u copied jar in WEB-INF or WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: I kept it in WEB-INF/lib and not its working Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add the jar file used for the connection, 'sqljdbc4' or 'sqljdbc' inside the lib folder of the axis2 home folder.